# $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

There is a function in psych package called 'alpha' which gives out various statistics. I want a specific column from the output so I use a code. This code works perfectly in console but it doesn't work when I try to use it in shiny.

```
library(shiny)
library(mirt)#This contains a dataset called deAyala
library(psych)#This has the alpha() function

server<- shinyServer(
    
    function(input, output) {
        
        output$data <- renderUI({
            
            alpha(deAyala,warnings=FALSE)$item.stats$raw.r #Warning disables the warnings 
            
            
            
        })
        
        
    }
)


ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel(title = h4("Output", align="center")),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("data"),
            
        )
        
    )
    
))


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `renderTable` or `renderText` to display the output instead of `renderUI`.

```
library(shiny)

server<- shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    output$data <- renderTable({
      alpha(deAyala,warnings=FALSE)$item.stats$raw.r
    })
  }
)

ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = h4("Output", align="center")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("data"),
    )
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: The only reason i still have my job is because of you Ronak. Thank you

Comment: I'll buy you a coffee as soon as i get my first payment

Comment: No worries. I am glad my answers are helpful to you.

Comment: Can you help out with this perhaps ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67927608/how-to-print-multiple-plots-using-plot-function-in-shiny-app