# How to print multiple plots using a single renderPlot() function in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have an app which outputs multiple plots. The app essentially takes some data in a specific form and then splits it and then calculates some proportion tables. It then makes graphs of these various tables. In the app below I am printing out only 'one' plot and it works. The issue comes when I have multiple plots(read below).**I did find some answers online on how to do this but I failed to implement them in my code**. This is my first shiny app so I am not really able to figure it out.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = h4("proportion graphs", align="center")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot"),
                  
      )
      
    )
    
  ))


server<-shinyServer(
  
  function(input, output) {
    
    l<- reactive({
    f<- list(`0` = structure(list(X70 = "D", X71 = "C", X72 = "C", X73 = "A", X74 = "B", X75 = "C", X76 = "D", X77 = NA_character_, X78 = "B", X79 = "D", X80 = "C", Q = 1), row.names = 32L, class = "data.frame"), `1` = structure(list(X70 = c("D", "B", "D", "D", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), X71 = c("B", "B", "C", "C", "C", NA, "D", "B", "C", "A", "C"), X72 = c("A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "B", NA), X73 = c("B", "C", "C", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "C", NA), X74 = c("B", "A", "C", "D", "B", "D", NA, "D", "D", "D", NA), X75 = c("C", "C", "B", "C", "D", "D", "C", "A", "C", "C", "C"), X76 = c("D", "A", "D", "B", "D", "C", "D", "A", "A", "D", "B"), X77 = c("D", "C", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "D"), X78 = c("B", "C", "C", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", NA), X79 = c("C", "C", NA, NA, "D", "A", "A", "A", "D", "A", "D"), X80 = c("B", "A", NA, NA, "B", "C", "B", NA, "B", "C", "A"), Q = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1)), row.names = c(8L, 10L, 12L, 17L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 33L, 35L, 38L, 45L), class = "data.frame"), `2` = structure(list(X70 = c("D", "D", "D", "B", "D", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), X71 = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "D", "B"), X72 = c("D", "C", "D", "A", "A", "C", "D", "C", NA, "D", "C", "B"), X73 = c("B", "D", "D", "C", "B", "D", "D", "D", NA, NA, "C", "A"), X74 = c("D", "C", "B", "D", "C", "B", "C", "C", "B", NA, "C", "D"), X75 = c("B", "C", "C", "C", NA, "C", "B", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C"), X76 = c("A", "D", "D", "D", NA, "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D"), X77 = c("B", "B", "D", "B", NA, "B", "D", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), X78 = c("C", "D", "C", "B", NA, "D", "C", "C", "B", "D", "C", NA), X79 = c("A", "D", "D", "D", NA, "D", "A", NA, "A", "D", "B", NA), X80 = c(NA, "C", "C", "A", NA, "C", "C", NA, "B", "C", "C", NA), Q = c(2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1)), row.names = c(4L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 15L, 16L, 21L, 22L, 26L, 37L, 39L, 43L), class = "data.frame"), `3` = structure(list(X70 = c("A", "A", "D", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", NA, "D", "D", "D"), X71 = c("B", "C", "D", "D", "C", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C", "A", "D"), X72 = c("B", "C", NA, "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "C", "D", "B"), X73 = c(NA, "C", "C", "A", "D", "C", "A", "A", "D", "B", "D", "B"), X74 = c(NA, "C", "D", "B", "A", "D", NA, "D", "B", "A", "D", "A"), X75 = c(NA, "C", "B", "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C", "D"), X76 = c(NA, "D", "A", "B", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), X77 = c(NA, "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "A", "B", NA, "C", "D", "D"), X78 = c(NA, "C", "C", "B", "C", "B", "A", "C", "D", "C", "C", "C"), X79 = c(NA, "D", "D", NA, "B", "D", "A", "D", "A", "D", "D", "A"), X80 = c(NA, "C", "C", NA, "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C"), Q = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2)), row.names = c(2L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 29L, 30L, 34L, 36L, 41L, 44L), class = "data.frame"), `4` = structure(list(X70 = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), X71 = c("A", NA, "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C"), X72 = c("B", "C", "C", "C", NA, "C", "B", "A", "C", "B", NA, "A"), X73 = c(NA, "D", "D", "D", "B", "D", "D", "D", "C", "A", "A", "C"), X74 = c("C", "A", "C", "D", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "D", "D", "D"), X75 = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "C", "C"), X76 = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "A"), X77 = c(NA, "B", "D", "B", NA, "B", "B", "B", "C", "D", NA, "C"), X78 = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C"), X79 = c("D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "A", "D", "C", "C"), X80 = c("C", "C", "C", "C", NA, "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A"), Q = c(2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4)), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 23L, 24L, 31L, 40L, 42L, 46L, 47L, 48L), class = "data.frame")) 
})


u<- reactive({u<- c("D", "B", "C", "A")})

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      
      l<-l()
      u<-u()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      
      out <- lapply(l, function(dat) 
        asplit(as.data.frame(t(sapply(dat, function(x) 
          proportions(table(factor(unlist(x), levels = u)))))), 1) ) %>%
        transpose %>%
        map(bind_rows, .id = 'grp')
      
      matplot(out[[1]][-1], type = "l", col = 1:4, xaxt = "n")
      axis(side=1, at=1:4, labels=colnames(out[[1]][-1]))
      legend("topleft", legend = colnames(out[[1]][-1]), fill = 1:4)
      
      
      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    })
    
    
    

  }
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

**If I try to print multiple graphs by using this code, it does not work. How can I fix this? This code works in the console but not in the shiny app**

```
     matplot(x[-1], type = "l", col = 1:4, xaxt = "n")
     axis(side=1, at=1:4, labels=colnames(x[-1]))
     legend("topleft", legend = colnames(x[-1]), fill = 1:4)
})
```

Comment: Can you use `ggplot` instead ? I am not sure if all the features of base plot are compatible with shiny.

Comment: I have posted a solution i found. Thank you for looking into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ui**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
      titlePanel(title = h4("proportion graphs", align="center")), sidebarLayout( sidebarPanel( ),
                                                                              
                                                                              mainPanel(
                                                                                # create a uiOutput
                                                                                uiOutput("plots")
                                                                              )
  )
  
))
```

**Sever**

```
shinyServer(
  
  function(input, output) {
    
    l<- reactive({
      f<- list(`0` = structure(list(X70 = "D", X71 = "C", X72 = "C", X73 = "A", X74 = "B", X75 = "C", X76 = "D", X77 = NA_character_, X78 = "B", X79 = "D", X80 = "C", Q = 1), row.names = 32L, class = "data.frame"), `1` = structure(list(X70 = c("D", "B", "D", "D", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), X71 = c("B", "B", "C", "C", "C", NA, "D", "B", "C", "A", "C"), X72 = c("A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "B", NA), X73 = c("B", "C", "C", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "C", NA), X74 = c("B", "A", "C", "D", "B", "D", NA, "D", "D", "D", NA), X75 = c("C", "C", "B", "C", "D", "D", "C", "A", "C", "C", "C"), X76 = c("D", "A", "D", "B", "D", "C", "D", "A", "A", "D", "B"), X77 = c("D", "C", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "D"), X78 = c("B", "C", "C", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", NA), X79 = c("C", "C", NA, NA, "D", "A", "A", "A", "D", "A", "D"), X80 = c("B", "A", NA, NA, "B", "C", "B", NA, "B", "C", "A"), Q = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1)), row.names = c(8L, 10L, 12L, 17L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 33L, 35L, 38L, 45L), class = "data.frame"), `2` = structure(list(X70 = c("D", "D", "D", "B", "D", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), X71 = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "D", "B"), X72 = c("D", "C", "D", "A", "A", "C", "D", "C", NA, "D", "C", "B"), X73 = c("B", "D", "D", "C", "B", "D", "D", "D", NA, NA, "C", "A"), X74 = c("D", "C", "B", "D", "C", "B", "C", "C", "B", NA, "C", "D"), X75 = c("B", "C", "C", "C", NA, "C", "B", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C"), X76 = c("A", "D", "D", "D", NA, "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D"), X77 = c("B", "B", "D", "B", NA, "B", "D", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), X78 = c("C", "D", "C", "B", NA, "D", "C", "C", "B", "D", "C", NA), X79 = c("A", "D", "D", "D", NA, "D", "A", NA, "A", "D", "B", NA), X80 = c(NA, "C", "C", "A", NA, "C", "C", NA, "B", "C", "C", NA), Q = c(2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1)), row.names = c(4L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 15L, 16L, 21L, 22L, 26L, 37L, 39L, 43L), class = "data.frame"), `3` = structure(list(X70 = c("A", "A", "D", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", NA, "D", "D", "D"), X71 = c("B", "C", "D", "D", "C", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C", "A", "D"), X72 = c("B", "C", NA, "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "C", "D", "B"), X73 = c(NA, "C", "C", "A", "D", "C", "A", "A", "D", "B", "D", "B"), X74 = c(NA, "C", "D", "B", "A", "D", NA, "D", "B", "A", "D", "A"), X75 = c(NA, "C", "B", "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C", "D"), X76 = c(NA, "D", "A", "B", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), X77 = c(NA, "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "A", "B", NA, "C", "D", "D"), X78 = c(NA, "C", "C", "B", "C", "B", "A", "C", "D", "C", "C", "C"), X79 = c(NA, "D", "D", NA, "B", "D", "A", "D", "A", "D", "D", "A"), X80 = c(NA, "C", "C", NA, "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C"), Q = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2)), row.names = c(2L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 29L, 30L, 34L, 36L, 41L, 44L), class = "data.frame"), `4` = structure(list(X70 = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), X71 = c("A", NA, "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C"), X72 = c("B", "C", "C", "C", NA, "C", "B", "A", "C", "B", NA, "A"), X73 = c(NA, "D", "D", "D", "B", "D", "D", "D", "C", "A", "A", "C"), X74 = c("C", "A", "C", "D", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "D", "D", "D"), X75 = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "C", "C"), X76 = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "A"), X77 = c(NA, "B", "D", "B", NA, "B", "B", "B", "C", "D", NA, "C"), X78 = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C"), X79 = c("D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "A", "D", "C", "C"), X80 = c("C", "C", "C", "C", NA, "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A"), Q = c(2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4)), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 23L, 24L, 31L, 40L, 42L, 46L, 47L, 48L), class = "data.frame")) 
    })
      
      
      
      u <- reactive({
        u <- c("D", "B", "C", "A")
      })
      
      # reactive expression to process data
      out <- reactive({
        l <- l()
        u <- u()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        
        lapply(l, function(dat) 
          asplit(as.data.frame(t(sapply(dat, function(x) 
            proportions(table(factor(unlist(x), levels = u)))))), 1) ) %>%
          transpose %>%
          map(bind_rows, .id = 'grp')
      })
      
      # render UI
      output$plots <- renderUI({
        
        lapply(1:length(out()[-1]), function(i) {
          # creates a unique ID for each plotOutput
          id <- paste0("plot_", i)
          plotOutput(outputId = id)
          
          # render each plot
          output[[id]] <- renderPlot({
            x <- out()[[i]][-1]
            matplot(x, type = "l", col = 1:4, xaxt = "n")
            axis(side=1, at=1:4, labels=colnames(x))
            legend("topleft", legend = colnames(x), fill = 1:4)
          })
          
        })
        
      })
      
    } )
```